# How to remove line break between index subentries

Tags: line-breaking, indexing, imakeidx

I am using the `imakeidx` package to generate and format my indices. What I want is to remove the linebreak between two subentries of the index. This way, the entries belonging to the same index category will be placed one next to the other -separated by a comma or another user-defined separator.

Below I provide a MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{imakeidx}
\makeindex[name=wdes,title=Initia Heirmorum,columns=1] 

\begin{document}
\lipsum \index[wdes]{1st!38@38, 35}
\lipsum \index[wdes]{1st!38@38, 30}
\lipsum \index[wdes]{1st!38}
\lipsum \index[wdes]{1st!25@25}
\lipsum \index[wdes]{2nd!a}
\lipsum \index[wdes]{2nd!b}
\printindex[wdes]
\end{document}
```

The generated index in the output looks like this:
[image: Image1]

What I need is something like the following:
[image: Image2]

Any ideas???

Comment: My current `.ist` file looks like this: 
`delim_0 "\\dotfill "
delim_1 ": "
delim_2 " \\dotfill "`
but I considered it irrelevant to mention. In the above output I use no `.ist` file.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

What you have to do is to create a file named `mystyle.ist` with the following contents:

```
item_1 ", "
```

Then add the option `options=-s mystyle` when you are generating the index

```
\makeindex[name=wdes,title=Initia Heirmorum,columns=1,options=-s mystyle]
```

and you're done.

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{imakeidx}
\makeindex[name=wdes,title=Initia Heirmorum,columns=1,options=-s mystyle]

\begin{document}
\lipsum \index[wdes]{1st!38@38, 35}
\lipsum \index[wdes]{1st!38@38, 30}
\lipsum \index[wdes]{1st!38}
\lipsum \index[wdes]{1st!25@25}
\lipsum \index[wdes]{2nd!a}
\lipsum \index[wdes]{2nd!b}
\printindex[wdes]
\end{document}
```

Output

[image]

If you use your style file that you mentioned in the comments, its contents should be then

```
delim_0 "\\dotfill "
delim_1 ": "
delim_2 " \\dotfill "
item_1 ", "
```

and the result will be

[image]

For online references see, for example http://www.miwie.org/tex-refs/html/makeindex-style-file.html#makeindex-output-style-specs. This is of course described in "The LaTeX Companion", if you have it.

Comment: @karlkoeller, that works fine! Thanks for the reference as well. It will save a lot of time and questions!

Answer (score 2):

I suggest

```
delim_1 "; "
item_1 ",  "
```

in a separate `longlines.ist` since this make es clear distinction between index number and page number. The linebreak is from `item_1` setting if not set as above.

Add the `options=-s longlines.ist` to the `\makeindex` options list.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{imakeidx}
\makeindex[name=wdes,title=Initia Heirmorum,columns=1,options=-s longlines.ist]

\begin{document}
\lipsum \index[wdes]{1st!38@38, 35}
\lipsum \index[wdes]{1st!38@38, 30}
\lipsum \index[wdes]{1st!38}
\lipsum \index[wdes]{1st!25@25}
\lipsum \index[wdes]{2nd!a}
\lipsum \index[wdes]{2nd!b}
\printindex[wdes]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is the same as my answer, once again...

Comment: @karlkoeller: Just a few seconds after you and I introduced `;` as index separator. I won't delete this time

Comment: This is already in the OP's style file

Comment: @karlkoeller: Do you demand me to delete it? ;-) And it's `;`, not `:` ... I had not seen the comment by the OP at all.

Comment: I don't demand it, of course :-)